# How to get list of Revision tags via gcloud for a particular Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I want to use the gcloud CLI to get a list of all the tags assigned to a specific Cloud Run Service.

I've been taking a look at the Run Describe CLI, however this doesn't return the Tags

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/revisions/describe

Is there a way to list all the Tags assigned, to all revisions for a particular Service?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, there is no specific command that will provide output to the list of all the tags assigned to a specific Cloud Run Service.

I would highly suggest to file a feature request in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/). Provide as much details on how you'd like this feature to work, some examples that will improve the chance of it being implemented.

**Note:** There is no guaranteed ETA for a feature request.